# Excel Tiered Charing Query

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to use a formula to work out a tiered charging structure for investments.

The client gets charged 0.75% on the first 2 million then 0.20% thereafter.

What I have is `=(2000000x0.75%+(SUM(CELL WITH TOTAL INVESTMENT VALUE)-2000000x0.2%)` but I can't get the correct figure.

In this example the figures I'm using are:

Total value = £3,716,474.88
What the answer should be is £15,000 + £3,432.95 = £18,432.95

Comment: I don't see how your formula gives you ANY figure at all.  It is not valid syntax.

Comment: The answer below worked

Comment: Try this one as well, `=MMULT((A1>{1,2000001})*(A1-{1,2000001}),{0.75;-0.55})`

Comment: Or, simply this one, `=MIN(2000000,A1)*0.75+MAX(0,A1-2000000)*0.2` where `A1` is 3716474.88

Answer (score -1, accepted):

THIS SHOULD GET YOU THE ANSWER

=IF(A1<2000000,A1*0.75,((A1-2000000)*0.2)+(2000000*0.75))

If the value is below 2 mil it will directly take 0.75% if not then first take 2 mil.75% then will subtract and take .2% then will add it

Comment: why did my answer got negative respone is it not right?